# Convert SQL to SQLAlchemy one

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have this SQL code and I want to execute it with SQLAlchemy.
But I can't manage to write a proper query with SQLAlchemy.

```
SELECT anon_1.applications_versions_id             AS versions_id,
       anon_1.applications_versions_application_id AS versions_application_id,
       anon_1.applications_versions_version        AS version,
       anon_1.applications_versions_status         AS status,
       anon_1.applications_id                      AS applications_id,
       anon_1.applications_developer_id            AS developer_id,
       anon_1.applications_name                    AS name,
       anon_1.applications_description             AS description
FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON
             (applications_versions.application_id) applications_versions.id             AS applications_versions_id,
                                                    applications_versions.application_id AS applications_versions_application_id,
                                                    applications_versions.version        AS applications_versions_version,
                                                    applications_versions.path           AS applications_versions_path,
                                                    applications_versions.status         AS applications_versions_status,
                                                    applications_versions.release_notes  AS applications_versions_release_notes,
                                                    applications_versions.created        AS applications_versions_created,
                                                    applications_versions.updated        AS applications_versions_updated,
                                                    applications.id                      AS applications_id,
                                                    applications.developer_id            AS applications_developer_id,
                                                    applications.name                    AS applications_name,
                                                    applications.description             AS applications_description,
                                                    applications.created                 AS applications_created,
                                                    applications.updated                 AS applications_updated
         FROM applications
                  JOIN applications_versions ON applications.id = applications_versions.application_id
         ORDER BY applications_versions.application_id, applications_versions.created DESC) AS anon_1
WHERE anon_1.applications_versions_status = 'DECLINED'
ORDER BY anon_1.applications_versions_application_id, anon_1.applications_versions_created DESC;
```

**Could someone help me with this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions here.

1. Simple

You wrap query in `from_statement` and work with it further.

Example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
apps = session.query(Application).from_statement(text(
"""
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
""")).all()
```

2. Hard

You learn SQLAlchemy and rewrite it yourself.

These links will help you:

- [SELECT, WHERE and ORDER BY operators in SQLAlchemy ORM](https://riptutorial.com/sqlalchemy/topic/2020/the-orm)
- [Common Table Expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.cte) (This function creates a subquery from your query)